# Ruby continuously output stdout of a long running shell command

Tags: ruby, shell

How can I continuously output the results of a long running shell command, as the output becomes available?

Currently I need to do this (which I can only see after command has finished)

> puts `long_running_shell_command`

What I want to do conceptually is

> puts_immediately  `long_running_shell_command`

Comment: how are you executing your shell command? the execution style you choose dictates whether you'll get a data stream (which gets continuously output) or buffered data (which is printed all at once).

Answer (score 4):

Redirect the output to `STDOUT`:

```
# waits a second, prints the current directory's contents, waits 5 seconds
system('sleep 1; ls; sleep 5', out: STDOUT)
```

Comment: Simple and effective.

Answer (score 2):

My favorite way to work with shell commands is like so:

```
Open3.popen3 "shellcommand --args --more-args" do |stdin, stdout, stderr, thread|
  while line = stdout.gets
    puts line
  end
end
```

The command gives you input, output and error streams. You can call `stdout.gets` to get the next line of output (my favorite), or `stdout.getc` for the next character, if you really want immediacy. The function waits until input is available and then returns `nil` when the command completes, so a common technique is to wrap the command in a while-loop and have a set of commands repeatedly execute until the command completes.